# How to turn repeated ranking(1-5) row data to column data in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table data:

```
ID      Sale    Weekday
1       12      1
2       15      2
3       16      3
4       17      4
5       18      5
6       11      1
7       13      2
8       14      3
9       15      4
10      20      5
11      25      1
12      14      2
13      18      3
14      21      4
15      11      5
..      ..
```

I'd like to turn it into:

```
Mo   Tu   We   Th   Fr
12   15   16   17   18
11   13   14   15   20
25   14   18   21   11
..
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(case when Weekday = 1 then Sale else 0 end) as mn,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 2 then Sale else 0 end) as Tu,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 3 then Sale else 0 end) as We,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 4 then Sale else 0 end) as Th,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 5 then Sale else 0 end) as Fr
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
          Row_number()OVER(partition by weekday ORDER BY ID ) as seq_no
    FROM   tablename
) A
Group by seq_no
```

As mentioned in sample data if your table has all 5 days for all the week

```
SELECT SUM(case when Weekday = 1 then Sale else 0 end) as mn,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 2 then Sale else 0 end) as Tu,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 3 then Sale else 0 end) as We,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 4 then Sale else 0 end) as Th,
       SUM(case when Weekday = 5 then Sale else 0 end) as Fr
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
          ( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY ID ) - 1 ) / 5 ) + 1 seq_no
    FROM   tablename
) A
Group by seq_no
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92950/6)**

Comment: Users dumps their data here, you do the work for them. I've seen countless people not doing any sort of research. They have a paying job and if it takes more than 2 brain cells to solve something, they post it here and expect other people to solve it for them... FOR FREE! A bit like cats used to be free animals and could take care of themselves and now they can't no longer because people just gave them food. Those cats can no longer live a free life because they don't know how to take care of themselves anymore. Similar things for developers like the OP...

Comment: @TT. - Yes that is true. I felt this question is little different so posted one as answer :)

Comment: I'm sure you do this for fun and I also do solve some issues posted on SO for fun. But questions that dump data and ask here's the data I want, without any indication of research, that I do not do. If I would I would just help perpetuate creating bad/lazy developers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `pivot` operator together with a partitioned `row_number` like this:

```
select
    max([1]) as 'Mo',
    max([2]) as 'Tu',
    max([3]) as 'We',
    max([4]) as 'Th',
    max([5]) as 'Fr' 
from 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by weekday order by id) rn 
    from your_table
) a
pivot (max(sale) for weekday in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) p
group by rn;
```